# How to differentiate between a left-click and a left-click and drag action?

Tags: autohotkey

I have an application (Royal TS) which embeds PuTTY sessions within the application's main window. However, if another application's window is obscuring the embedded PuTTY session, and I click on the embedded PuTTY session, the Royal TS window *does not* come to the front.

So, I tried to resolve this with the following AutoHotKey script:

```
LButton::                             ; Detect left mouse button click
MouseGetPos, xpos, ypos, win_id       ; Get mouse position and window ID 
WinGetTitle, title, ahk_id %win_id%   ; Get window title
WinGetClass, class, ahk_id %win_id%   ; Get window class

if class=PuTTY                        ; If clicked in an emmbeded PuTTY window...
{                                     ;
  IfWinExist, Royal TS                ; ...and Royal TS is running...
  {                                   ;
    WinActivate                       ; ...bring Royal TS to the front
  }                                   ;
}                                     ;
else                                  ; Else, it wasn't a PuTTY window clicked...
{                                     ;
  MouseClick, left, xpos, ypos        ; ...just pass mouse button click through
}                                     ;
return                                ;
```

This works fine...up to a point. The problem occurs when I attempt to click and hold *any* application's title bar to drag it (or resize an application's window) the script runs and intercepts my left button but the intention to drag or resize a window is lost because of the MouseClick command towards the end of the script.

How can I differentiate between a left-click and a left-click and drag action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `LButton::` to `~LButton::` and remove the `else` statement.

`~` will make left mouse button work as usual, but will still run the code.

Comment: Actually, there was a small problem with the 'WinActivate' command...if I clicked on an embedded PuTTY session the Royal TS window _was_ activated (brought to the front) but the PuTTY session did not have the focus (i.e., if I started typing after clicking the PuTTY session my text was not entered into the session). I resolved this by replacing the WinActivate command with two WinSet commands:


`WinSet, AlwaysOnTop, On, Royal TS`

`WinSet, AlwaysOnTop, Off, Royal TS`